# Type mismatch. Required: Observer<in Int!> Found:?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I want to Observe live data change in ViewModel and want to change another live data so I am using Mediatorlivedata, I don't know how to observe it in ViewModel, I am getting the compile-time error 
**Type mismatch. Required: Observer Found: ?**

```
class CheckmeasureViewModel(private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {

var estimateFinancialyear: ArrayList<FinYear> = ArrayList()
var asset = arrayListOf("Select")
var estimate = arrayListOf("Select")
var appPref: AppPref
var estimateyearpos = MutableLiveData<Int>()
var mediatorLiveData: MediatorLiveData<Int> = MediatorLiveData()

init {
    appPref = AppPref.getInstance()!!
    estimateFinancialyear.add(FinYear(0, "Select"))
    estimateFinancialyear.addAll(repository.getFinYears())



    estimateyearpos.observeForever(object : Observer<in Int> {
        fun onChanged(@Nullable integer: Int?) { //Do something with "integer"
        }
    })
}
```

}[image]

Answer (score 1):

You Shouldn't observe a live data on the viewModel, try adding it as a source to a mediatorLiveData and observing it directly on the view:

```
val mediatorLiveData: MediatorLiveData<Int> = MediatorLiveData().apply{
   addSource(estimateyearpos) { /*Do something with "integer" */}
}
```

or even (if you don't need it to be mutable)

```
val liveData = Transformations.map(estimateyearpos) { /*Do something with "integer" */}
```

Both of this options will observe the source live data and apply the given function to it, but you still need to observe it on an Activity or a fragment to properly get the values.

Comment: val liveData = Transformations.map(estimateyearpos) { /*Do something with "integer" */} this is not triggering or observing on change of this estimateyearpos

Comment: I want to trigger another spinner on change of estimateyearpos so I am trying to observe in ViewModel itself

Comment: Well, I don't get it but you could try `estimateyearpos.observeForever {  intValue -> /*Do something with "integer" */}`  . But you really shouldn't observe a live data outside of the view layer